# Get field of fetched entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3
I try to run this query

```
@Query("""
  select distinct new com.acme.person.dto.OtherPersonDuplicate(p.idEditeur, p.code, pon.otherName, p.city) 
  from PersonOtherName pon
  join fetch pon.person p
  WHERE lower(pon.otherName) like lower(:name)
""")
 public List<OtherPersonDuplicate> findDuplicate(String name);
```

> org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: query specified join fetching,
> but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select
> list

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for the association `pon.person` to be fetched.
But you're not returning `pon` from the query (it's not in the `select` list).
So there's no reason to fetch it.

Perhaps you mean to use a regular `join` instead of a `fetch join`.